# WCF with Entity Framework Code First relationship

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

I'm learning WCF, and tried to make a small service that exposes a Project and its tasks (the standard Entity Framework hello world).

The class structure is the following:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual Project RelatedProject { get; set; }
}
```

The DB context comes after:

```
public class ProjectContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, the service endpoint:

```
    public IEnumerable<Project> getProjects()
    {
        ProjectContext p = new ProjectContext();
        return p.Projects.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

The problem is that this model will throw a System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, but, If I remove the virtual properties from the model, It would work, but I would loose the entity framework links between Project and Task.

Anyone with a similar setup?

Comment: Does it work if you include the `Tasks`?  `return p.Projects.Include(p => p.Tasks).AsEnumerable();`

Comment: This won't even compile, but I see the idea, I'll follow this option ;)

Comment: Hmm, hadn't tried it (obviously), but found that on the [ADO.NET Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx) :\

Answer (score 2):

I banged my head against the wall several hours with this one. After extensive debugging, google gave the answer and I feel right to post it here since this was the first result I got in google.

Add this class on top of your `[ServiceContract]` interface declaration (typically `IProjectService.cs`

```
public class ApplyDataContractResolverAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription description, BindingParameterCollection parameters)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription description, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientOperation proxy)
    {
        var dataContractSerializerOperationBehavior =
            description.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
        dataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.DataContractResolver =
            new ProxyDataContractResolver();
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription description, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperation dispatch)
    {
        var dataContractSerializerOperationBehavior =
            description.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
        dataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.DataContractResolver =
            new ProxyDataContractResolver();
    }

    public void Validate(OperationDescription description)
    {
        // Do validation.
    }
}
```

Requirements are

```
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
```

Then under the `[OperationContract]` keyword add `[ApplyDataContractResolver]` keyword and you are set!

Big thanks to http://blog.rsuter.com/?p=286

Answer (score 0):

For sending data trough WCF you should disable lazy loading (`dataContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`).

To be sure the data you want is loaded you need to use eager loading ( trough the Include method).

You need to change your function to:

```
 public IEnumerable<Project> getProjects()
    {
        ProjectContext p = new ProjectContext();
        p.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        return p.Projects.Include("Tasks").AsEnumerable();
    }
```

Comment: No luck, still getting this error: The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.